# Set function and decimal number

Tags: python, set

Can someone help me to understand the relationship between the `set` function and decimal numbers?

For instance:

```
print(set([1.104 , 2.1 , 3.25 , 4.45 , 5.553 , 6 , 7 , 8]))
```

gives this output:

```
{4.45, 3.25, 6, 7, 8, 2.1, 1.104, 5.553}
```

Comment: What is weird about that?

Comment: A set is unordered by nature, which is where I think you may be getting confused

Comment: FYI, `set` isn't a function; it's a *type*, and as is usual for a type, calling it returns an instance of the type. In this case, the elements of the argument are added to the set, though the order in which they are added is ignored, and the `set` uses an ordering that is convenient for how the elements are stored (which is in a hash table).

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an **unordered** collection of **distinct** hashable objects.
> Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
> sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
> union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see
> the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections
> module.)
> ...
> **Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion.**

So you should not assume (even though it may happen) that its implementation iterates over the elements in the order you put them in.

Also notice that the elements are distinct, so calling set([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]) will return a set {1,2,3,4}.